# What does the "Volume Level" in Spotify do?

Tags: volume-control, spotify

What does the "Volume Level" option in the Spotify settings do?

[image: Volume level (Adjust the volume for your environment): Quiet]

I don't notice anything when changing it. A coarse volume level like this also seems redundant to the system-wide volume level.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Spotify for a long while but from memory the volume setting affects the *next* song, not the current song.And you would need to disable *Normalize Volume* logically speaking.

This [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/spotify/comments/7w2iju/new_volume_setting_in_android_app/dtxmhax/) says the same with more description

> .... changing the volume level in setting will affect the next song you will listen to but not the one you are currently listening to